# Objects with their own intrinsic value. Another way to do getters

Tags: javascript, object, getter

I wanted to be able to create an object that had it's own intrinsic value.  That way I could use it in an expression as if it was a regular variable.   It turned out to be quite easy - so easy I am wondering if I am missing something.  All it seems to take is to make sure the object contains a method "valueOf". Like so:

```
var p = {
  a: 12;
  valueOf: function(){return this.a+12}
  }

alert(p/3); // =8
```

It's probably a good idea to include a "toString" method too.  What seems to be happening is that without the valueOf method, a reference to the object goes up the prototype chain until it finds the method on Object, which just returns "object Object".   By providing a local one, the method can return anything.

It seems to work in all browsers that I tried.

It is really another way to provide a getter-like functionality.  But a little better because getters can only be applied to properties of objects.  This way you can use the object itself.

What do you think?  Is this safe?  Any pitfalls?

Comment: *"It is really another way to provide a getter-like functionality"* - how so? Getters provide access to members, here you're overriding the value of the object itself.

Comment: True.  But it is like  a getter in that you can refer to the value with just a variable-like reference.  Also, the object still has all its properties in full force.   It's just an extra thing you can do with the object.

Answer (score 0):

Well I started using this pattern and found one issue.  If you create an object p like the one above, you have to guess how the interpreter will view a reference to the object.

For example, if P is used in arithmetic expression, it calls the object's valueOf() method to get its value.  But when you try to access a property of p such as p.a, then it treats p as an object and retrieves the property as you expect.

In a getter, by contrast, accessing p.a when there is a getter on p would first run the getter and then try to get the property 'a' of the result.  Subtly different, but important.

It's all quite correct and seems to "guess" correctly what to do.  But using the pattern does rely on knowing this behavior, which AFAIK is not documented anywhere.